Finding the application causing "Passwords are locked" dialog
Some application constantly tries to access my Keychain-saved passwords, causing the "Passwords are locked" dialog window to show up.
How can I find which application tries to access my passwords?


Are you browsing when this happens?

Which applications are running when this happens?

I am a power user so I have 25+ applications running, multiple web browsers, password managers, etc.

Isolate and identify: quit an app and see if the behavior disappears, repeat with all other apps. If you get to the end and it still happens open Activity Monitor and look for processes that may belong to something you installed and quit them one at a time till you find the culprit.

@SteveChambers that is shooting in the dark - I posted the question here to get something more useful

Actually it is the root of troubleshooting, but if you think that someone has a better idea, by all means. Experience will give you some likely culprits, but as we can't look over your shoulder and/or work on the Mac ourselves you may be left with the brute force method.
